# Redis installation error ./redis-trib.rb not found

Tags: ruby, redis, rubygems

I am trying to install redis cluster in ubuntu server using ssh. I don't have sudo permissions to install something in the server.

When I was trying to use the command to create the cluster.

./redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 127.0.0.1:30000 
127.0.0.1:32000 127.0.0.1:32001 127.0.0.1:32002

I got the error as follows

./redis-trib.rb command not found.

I know that I need to install ruby gems to solve the issue. since I dont have sudo permisiion, can you suggest an alternate way to configure it.

Comment: I assume doing any installation would require an admin-level.

Comment: I don't have admin access. I am just running the binaries. is there any other way ?